# Substituting the values of a variable in sas

Tags: sas

I have a column in my sas file as age and another column as finalage. I want to substitute the values in age column by values in agefinal column for just one ID (that is 5)

The code that I used was:

```
Data temp;
set temp;
if ID = 5;
then age = agefinal;
run;
```

I could not substitute the values. The values in age column did not change. I tried to run this code to check the character length of values since character type is numeric for both the columns.

Code:

```
Proc contents data = temp;
tables age agefinal;
run;
```

The output that I got was:

```
age : character length 3.
agefinal: character length $3
```

I would appreciate your suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing the semicolon at the end of the if statement.  Right now what you're doing is deleting all records where the id isn't equal to five.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.. I did that already but it still didnt work.. Could it because of different character length?

Comment: No, SAS handles different lengths fine.  Does the SAS log give any notices when you run the data step?  It looks like you might have mistyped the variable names (are the two age fields supposed to be character?)

Comment: Yes. this is surprising because SAS log doesn't show anything. I have checked the variable names several times but it still does not work. The age fields field is numeric but of different character length.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the formats to be the same

```
data temp;
 modify temp;
 format age agefinal $3.;
 run;
```

and then see if it will let you do the substitution.

Answer (score 0):

The code you provided runs with an ERROR, remove the additional semicolon and that may fix your issue:

```
/* ORIGINAL */
Data temp;
set temp;
if ID = 5;
then age = agefinal;
run;

/* CORRECTED */
Data temp;
set temp;
if ID = 5 /* REMOVED SEMICOLON */
then age = agefinal;
run;
```

Cheers
Rob